# Signout/Switch Twitter user using SocialAuthAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, socialauth

I'm using SocialAuthAdapter lib in Android and I'm trying to switch Twitter user without success. What happens is after doing the following I do not get LogIn screen, but instead it signs in previous user:

```
adapter.getCurrentProvider().logout();
adapter.authorize(_parentActivity, Provider.TWITTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the signout method provided by latest socialauth android sdk.  The method above not clear cookies

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.signOut(HomeActivity.this, Provider.TWITTER.toString());
```